# Buttons inside GridView are not getting proper Id

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am designing a chess Board application and I am using a gridview for storing 64 buttons and assigning id to them starting from 0 to 63. But the ids are starting from 2 instead of 0, I can't understand why that is happening.

I am using ButtonAdapter class I made and the following is its getView() method and I set text of each button same as its id to make sure they are getting correct ids.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        Button button;

        if(view == null){
            button = new Button(mContext);
        }else{
            button = (Button)view;
        }

        button.setId(mIndex);
        button.setText(button.getId()+"");
        button.setTextSize(5);
        button.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, view.getId()+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
        mIndex++;
        return button;
    }
```

mIndex is initialized to 0 in my constructor like following

```
private Context mContext;
private int mIndex;
public ButtonAdapter(Context context){
        mContext = context;
        mIndex = 0;
    }
```

and the screenshot of result I am getting is below
[image]

Please help, I am a beginner. Sorry for any mistakes, thanks in advance.

Comment: share your whole Adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `mIndex`variable and increment because it will create issue when you will scroll.

You can use adapter position instead of `mIndex`.

```
        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            Button button;
            if(view == null){
                button = new Button(mContext);
            }else{
                button = (Button)view;
            }

            button.setId(i);
            button.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            button.setTextSize(5);
            button.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, view.getId()+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });
            return button;
        }
```

Comment: thanks, worked perfectly. But I can't understand why it was not working before,  I mean id the same sort of thing but how it started from 2, does this mean that the method getView() was called 2 times before the adapter started to fill the gridview...

Comment: @HarshDave yes, getView will call when you scroll so it will increment your variable

Answer (score 0):

you can set the tag like this

```
button.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
```

and get that id by

```
 Integer position = (Integer)view.getTag();
```